# How to retain words with a special character in r

Tags: r, special-characters

I have a set of words like this one:

```
ctr_names <- c("Czech_Republic","New_Zealand","Great_Britain", "Spain", "France")
```

I want to RETAIN JUST words with "_" characters and remove the rest of words. I wish a final result as:

```
[1] "Czech_Republic" "New_Zealand"    "Great_Britain"
```

I've been trying with

```
gsub("[_]", " ", ctr_names)
```

but it does not work because it remove the character I wanna retain.  Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
grep("_", ctr_names, value = TRUE)
```

`grep` functions match things. `sub` functions substitute things.

Comment: Good to hear, Feel free to vote and accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Tidyverse way:

```
library(stringr)
str_subset(ctr_names, "_")
```